# An explicit 'reply to comment' feature

Tags: feature-request, comments

New users to the site don't understand that to generate a notification for the user they are replying to in a comment, they have to prefix the recepient's username with an @ sign. It's just not obvious enough. I find myself telling new users to the site how to reply to comments every time.

Perhaps a more obvious 'reply' button could help? Or a way for users to effectively 'follow' a post, so that all new comments, and maybe answers, edits, etc. too generate a notification?

Comment: to whom would the button reply since there can be several parties in the comments?

Comment: @Plutonix A reply button next to your comment would have helped me if ever I forgot to put your username in the beginning.

Comment: ok, so a button for each comment.  It might help, but may be also be a bit too Forum/msg boardy

Comment: Nice idea. BTW this already exists in the android app.

Comment: @user000001 It is broken there, though.  I've noticed that if I reply to someone with non-ASCII characters in their handle, my phone inserts an escape sequence that I do not believe is the same as typing the actual unicode character, since it appears as an escape sequence when I view it on a desktop.

Comment: I doubt it would be very desirable to make it easier to have prolonged discussions via comments. I too didn't immediately realise that you needed to use '@username' to get a comment into someone's inbox, but its not hard to work out. Most people are just trying to say their piece anyway. They're not really interested in what other people have to say, except to correct them. If an extended conversation needs to occur, that could probably be done in a chat room.

Comment: There are numerous greasemonkey scripts floating around in the net that do this and more things (e.g. formatting comments nicer in a htreaded view9

Comment: Using `@` for referring others is a common approach followed in most of the app and I don't find any difficulty in using it.

Comment: so, it'll be another twitter?

Comment: @hjpotter92 no, that's just fud

Comment: Should this be marked status-complete now that the alternative in the last line of the post is now a thing?

Answer (score 54):

This isn't so much an answer as another opinion. I have always thought SO's comment system is pretty bad. I don't want a reply button on every comment, but I'd love a better comment notification system.

When someone else posts a comment on an answer I have previously commented on, I would like a notification, even if I wasn't @'d in the comment. It's a thread I'm interested in, because I commented. If this happened for every comment there would be no need for anyone to at-reply anyone.

Notifications are such a minor UI detail that I don't think this would annoy more than help. It's super easy to dismiss notifications if you don't care about them, and users with high rep already get tons of notifications, anyway. There could even be just one notification per comment section, so it would be the same as if just one person in the "thread" at-replied you.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'd like to see too. Perhaps the favourites feature could be modified to fire notifications too. What's the point of favouriting something? Just to see a golden star next to the question? 

Comment: Or "follow/unfollow", ala Facebook comments

Comment: @chris (*so* annoying having to type that just so you'll be notified!) that would be great, would be perfect if it turned on automatically when you comment, with a single button "unfollow" (or whatever) somewhere near the comments section.

Comment: @Chris As I suggested in the question.

Comment: @duci9y: See [this FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53585/how-do-favorite-questions-work) on favorite questions logic. As far as I know, favorite posts are highlighted for new comments on the question but not on answers - it would be nice if those would also be included. Also, of course notifications for them would also be nice to have - it seems to have been a planned feature for a long time, but never implemented in a final form.

Comment: @sgroves: I think subscribing to updates/comments on answers should be opt-in (perhaps similar to the favorite questions feature), and not performed automatically for every comment. It's very rare that I would be inclined to subscribe for all future comments after posting a comment focused on a specific issue or for clarification. I don't agree that notifications are a minor detail - in fact they are crucial for communication, and shouldn't contain any noise if they are to be effective.

Comment: @corsair992 i'd be fine with opt-in too. that's a matter of preference i suppose.

Comment: I guess I would like to see the numbers; how many comments are posted on questions I "follow" per minute. Sometimes you may be getting overflown with the amount of notifications specially if you are quite active in a few questions...

Comment: @mehow there could be just a single notification per comment "thread" telling you there are new comments in that thread. no need for a notification for each comment, in other words. that would help reduce clutter.

Answer (score 24):

I've been lead to believe that the functionality for comments has been kept deliberately minimal because comments are an unimportant part of the site. SO tries very hard to not be like a forum. Comments are more like a forum. The developers would probably consider more sophisticated functionality for comments as taking the software in the wrong direction.

Comment: this question is more about making existing reply functionality easier to use, though.

Comment: @sgroves "deliberately minimal" seems to cover "not necessarily easy to use" :)

Comment: features not being easy to use is *never* a good thing. if you don't want users using a feature, remove the feature. otherwise, make it easy to use just like everything else.

Comment: @sgroves No. Making a feature hard to reach can be very relevant. "Click here to format your hard drive" should not be on your desktop but still available. :)

Comment: i agree, but we're not talking about formatting your hard drive. we're talking about a non-destructive feature on a web app. and "hard to reach" != "easy to use". commenting is available to most users. it's obvious you can do it. it's just *hard to use*.

Comment: @sgroves We are talking about a feature that the organizers of the content don't want to be overused. Making it hard to use and therefore discouraging users to overuse it is a practical approach.

Comment: @AngeloNeuschitzer In other words, you're saying all suggestions for improving usability of comments should be ignored because the "organizers" (whoever *they* are, i thought SO was run by its users) don't want it overused. that's not a straw man, it's the gist of what you're saying. doesn't make any sense to me. surely there is nothing wrong with letting users in a comment thread know when someone comments. the system right now a) doesn't make much sense and b) is not very useful to anyone.

Comment: @sgroves: I think overused comments _will_ be a destructive feature at SE. SE sites are designed to contain questions, and multiple answers to the question. If anything has to improve, it's questions and answers. As I see, comments are there to _nudge_ so that questions and answer get better. I have seen many commentors correcting _each other_, while they should have been correcting the question/answer. Also, the _content_ of the site is run by users, not it's design. To figure out why it is better that _they_ control the design, just check the variety of feature requests in the meta sites.

Comment: you're still making the leap that the improvements suggested on this page will somehow make comments overused - quite a leap, i would say, considering these are just suggestions. nonetheless i still think comments can be improved without being destructive, as you say. isn't it at least worth discussing?

Comment: @sgroves: Considering that these "improvements" would be for the benefits of newcomers not familiar with how SE works, it is pretty much guaranteed that they will be overused.

Comment: why would they only benefit newcomers? read my answer in this thread. being notified when someone else comments on an answer i've also commented on would be enormously useful to me, and clearly many others too. i am not a new user, and i don't see how this feature would only benefit people unfamiliar with SO. it would benefit everyone who comments on answers.

Comment: @sgroves: The original question was for the benefit of new users. It _did_ provide a suggestion for users to be able to subscribe to a post (which is already partially available for questions via the favorites feature), but few people are going to follow every comment thread unless they are automatically subscribed to them as you suggest in your answer. As per my comment on it, I don't agree with it as an automated feature, although I would agree with non-invasive opt-in subscriptions. The issue presented in the question is not a real issue to be solved in my opinion.

Comment: i agree about the issue in the question. there's no good reason to have a reply button on every comment. that's unneeded (and potentially harmful) visual clutter.

Answer (score 4):

One cool part of using this site I've found myself quite fond of is to actually learn always more and more about how it works.

In the same way we gain reputation to see more content, review stuff, have more to say about what stays on the site, I find it very ok that people have some brain juice burnt to understand things such as putting an @ in front of a name.

which is also kind of... a normal way amongst the internets to attract someone attention.

now the fact that it will notify users wil be known to every individual somehow somewhen during their learning of SO.

Comment: Unfortunately, I see the reply feature coming in most useful for newcomers to the site.

Comment: @duci9y: It would definitely be _useful_ for newcomers, but would encouraging newcomers to use it frequently be useful for the overall site?

Comment: @corsair992 If use of the reply feature is to be discouraged, then there should not be a reply feature at all.

Comment: @duci9y not really... many features of this site (like flagging or voting) are actually 'limited' (40 votes per day, only so much flags at a time, 20 reviews per day) eg their use is somewhat 'discouraged' so that no abuse is made. Pinging people *can* be very harrassing and people, especially newcomers who will want an answer now if not sooner, should not be ablo to harrass others so easily. Unless you think there should not be a voting feature, since it's overuse is discouraged by the daily limit?

Answer (score 3):

An alternative could be to show user tags as soon as the comment box become active if there is more than one participant in the comment list:

So for example, currently when you type **@b**, it shows you options for who to select, could we not just show all users when the **add a comment** link is clicked:

[image]

That way as soon as the comment box is opened and there are comments from more than a single user it would show you the tags.

It would be pretty light weight to work it out, but perhaps with things like meta, if there are multiple commentators it should be limited and only work up to a maximum of 5 commentators?

Comment: If you come to meta (and more than once) you most likely already know about this, so I don't think this feature is relevant to it. But on the main site that would be a splendid idea.

Comment: Yeah, I know meta users would know this but the changes would be rolled out across all sites on SE. That's why my thinking on max commentators came in, as there are longer discussions in comments on meta.

Comment: I wish more people knew about the autocomplete feature of the username. I miss a lot of comments because people mistype my username incorrectly on a regular basis. The first two letters are hard to read depending on the font (`r` and `m`).

Answer (score 0):

**NO THANKS**

The reason sites like youtube have a reply to comment feature is because they get crap ton comments all the time. So it is practically IMPOSSIBLE to see what the conversation is without that feature.

SE is about content. This content is what's important, and it is resides in the question and the answers. The comments should never be an important part of the thread. They are there to get clarification from the questioner or answerer, and to give short advice or comment.

There really isn't a need for almost any SE post to have more than 10 comments. So this feature you're proposing would not help the site one bit, but would only possibly encourage people to comment more.

Comment: i think it would make comments more relevant and more helpful in creating better answers because people would actually be able to reply to comments in a timely and useful manner. THE biggest problem with comments on SO is that someone will comment and not get a response from others who have commented (they don't know because they weren't notified). this is why comments seem superfluous in the first place! the system is *totally broken*. if the comment system were better, *answers* would also improve.

Answer (score -10):

I'm in the (no more) silent majority that would find this useful, for two key reasons:

1. you can link the two comments. So, if the **original** comment was deleted, the system could **inform** you and you can **decide** if you want to delete also your comment or not.
2. the system can add a **link to the original comment**. Now it's a **nightmare** to find it. If the original comment is deleted, the link, obviously, will disappear.

Comment: You can't link to a _"deleted comment"_... It's deleted.

Comment: "The link to the original deleted comment... have you read the answer?" Yes, but I am having trouble to get the point. So the system would magically remove links like [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267088/an-explicit-reply-to-comment-feature/409406?noredirect=1#comment856590_409406)? Will it rip out the link, the link+text or the entire comment? Will it also remove manually created links?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I think it's very clear and simple: if the original comment is deleted, the link points to nowhere. So the link is no more displayed in the reply comment.

Comment: That sounds simple, but that's potentially a lot of links to check on every page load, or a lot of pages to check on every comment deletion... That seems practically impossible.

Comment: @Cerbrus It's now that volunteers must check manually if there are "dangling comments", because they replied to a comment that was deleted

Comment: On every page load you'd have to check if __all__ (comment) links on the page are still live. That means that you have to _parse_ every comment for every possible comment link format, and then check the found links against the database. That's __waaay__ too much processing to add to __every single page load__. The other way around, checking all existing comments when a comment is deleted is even worse. I like how you question my programming experience, yet you completely ignore the performance implications of what you suggest.

Comment: @MarcoSulla I'm not sure that removing the link is desirable in general. Imagine my comment above would magically have the link removed – is it obvious to people that this happened? Isn't it more useful to know that I *did* link to a comment which is just not accessible anymore? While I can see that there are *some* cases that would benefit from automatic removal, I am certain it's not *all* cases – in fact, I would guess only a minority of cases benefits from automatic removal.

Comment: There is no foreign keys on text contents. Comment links are just that.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi: Miyagi-senpai, I'm talking about the ***removed*** comment. If the user removed the comment, and someone replied to it, the link to the removed comment is useless

Comment: @MarcoSulla I have _**removed**_ my initial comment now. Do you think it is useless to know that my other comment indeed did link to a comment? Do you think the sentence "So the system would magically remove links like this one?" makes sense if there is no link? Even if the target does not exist anymore, knowing that there was one seems like relevant information.

Comment: @Cerbrus The doubts are legit. There's __no need__ to do what you say. Just add to the Comment table a nullable column "repliedTo" with a ON DELETE SET NULL. If someone do a normal comment, that field is null. If someone replies to the comment, the foreign key is populated with the id of the comment. If the FK is null, no link is showed on a __single__ page load. And note the `ON DELETE SET NULL`.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Miyagi-senpai, please re-read carefully the answer. I said that the user will be informed that the "father" comment was deleted

Comment: @MarcoSulla Your answer *also* says "If the original comment is deleted, the link, obviously, will disappear.". One of your comments says "if the original comment is deleted, the link points to nowhere. So the link is no more displayed in the reply comment."

Comment: Your suggestion doesn't mention any actual database-level link. I interpreted the "Link to the original comment" As something like: _"[@otherUser](https://othercomm.ent) Yea but bla bla."_ Just plain text.

Comment: A simple solution is not give a means to delete comments... If a mod has to clean up, I don't mind to throw away non-relevant comments, such as many of those that are in this answer... Moreover, my opinion is that the comment feature is not used appropriately in lots of circumstances. There are no problems if it is used right. 
Alas, the reply-to feature is only useful in a chat environment, of which the SO question/answer thread is clearly not eligible for that.

Comment: @Cerbrus You got me an idea. If you hover the link, an ajax request can load the original comment. You could also not click on the link

Comment: @KarelG No, it's just a way to improve the already existing chat, since I can mention someone in the comment. So why proposal makes it more chatty? It make it less!

Comment: Comments aren't meant for chat. This whole conversation on this answer is exactly what shouldn't be happening... For multiple reasons.

Comment: "_Improving the already existing chat_"? The comment feature on the question/answer(s) (again, that is the context of this thread) is not meant to be used as a chat feature! Moreover, there is already a mechanism that triggers an invitation if there are too many back-and forth comments between two persons; a chat room is opened if someone clicks on it. It is a proof that the comment feature is not meant to chat between people. Use it to _comment_ (or remark) something on the post you're commenting to.

Comment: @KarelG Yes, but calm, ok? My proposal makes more simple to remove "dangling comments", and to get the comment that the person is referring to. It does __not__ make this __more__ chatty, and it does have nothing in common with your comment

Comment: @KarelG I think it make it __less chatty__, because the user will be informed the "parent" comment was deleted, and he can decide to delete her/his comment too. This makes the site more clear in faster times, and alleviate the work of volunteers that remove useless comments. Please re-read carefully my answer.

Comment: The point is that most comments *should not* have a "parent" comment in the first place. Making it easier to use comments for chatting is just inviting people to do so.