# Better comment organization

Tags: discussion, feature-request, comments, comment-replies

Comments are second class citizens and it is pretty easy to get rid of the more useless ones by flagging them. We also discourage long comment conversations. However, comments are useful to point out mistakes or clarify information.

When replying to a particular user, you can write @username, which will send them a notification.

### Problem

For some popular answers, the number of comments can get quite long. This leads to two problems:

- When replies to different users are scattered throughout the list, it is hard see at a glance who/what they were replying to.
- When a user changes their name, it makes tracking the @reply very confusing. ([Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29665208/3681880) -- I assume @Rotwang is the old @DerGolom here, but it is hard to tell.) Renaming the @username string in the comment text is problematic. (See [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270105/changing-user-name-leaves-orphaned-comment-references) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31851/change-all-username-references-in-comments-when-a-user-changes-their-name).)

### Proposed solution

Stack Overflow is not a blog or a forum and while we don't want to encourage lots of comments, I think we could adopt one good aspect of blog/forum comments. That is, **when someone replies to a user or a comment, the reply would appear directly below that comment, slightly indented.** This would solve or at least greatly alleviate both of the problems mentioned above.

This would probably require an extra database table column identifying which comment the reply belongs to. It may not be feasible to apply this to old comments, but any new comments could follow this system.

An indirect benefit is that comment groups could be folded up (hidden) together or flagged as a set.

### Update

Seeing that one of the founders of Stack Overflow was very opposed to threaded comments (see [here](https://blog.codinghorror.com/discussions-flat-or-threaded/) and [here](https://blog.codinghorror.com/web-discussions-flat-by-design/), as @PaulRoub noted), I'm guessing this feature request will be a no go. I'm still curious if a single reply layer might work, though.

I'm adding the `discussion` tag for ideas of how this might be tweaked to solve the problems mentioned above without incurring the negative aspects of threaded discussion.

Comment: I have written an userscript to highlight comments that are likely replies to each others: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/251142/158100

Comment: I agree with this. Comments can be called second class citizens all day long, push comes to shove they are not to plenty of people using the site. Having more clarity in them when they're still acting like they're first class citizens gets my vote. Plus: if a comment gets deleted, all answers to it can be instantly cleaned up as well. Probably need restraints on replying to replies though, or the comments might turn into a mailing list / reddit.

Comment: I agree with [BoundaryImposition](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251139/highlight-replies-when-i-click-on-a-comment/251142#251142) who said and i quote " I'm saying that there should not be highlighting in comments. Making it easier to have conversations in comments will encourage people to have conversations in comments, despite the fact that people should not be having conversations in comments. It's really as simple as that" also "Do it in chat, instead, which already highlights reply-threads"

Comment: How would you solve the 'who this comment is a reply to' when there's 2 match on a short match (actually both match will get notified IIRC, how would you choose the comment to link to ?)

Comment: @Tensibai with a "reply to" icon next to the comment itself, was my idea. Where the delete icon would appear on your own comments.

Comment: @Gimby, something like that would also [help new users know how to reply](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267088/an-explicit-reply-to-comment-feature).

Comment: A couple of Jeff Atwood posts making the arguments *against* this more clearly than I could (my version would be "no, please, no, please don't"): [Discussions: Flat or Threaded?](https://blog.codinghorror.com/discussions-flat-or-threaded/), [Web Discussions: Flat by Design](https://blog.codinghorror.com/web-discussions-flat-by-design/)

Comment: @PaulRoub, Those are some strong arguments and make me reconsider my feature request. However, I'm reticent to say "Ok, fine, the current situation is the best we can do." Is there nothing we can do to improve the situation? Limit replies to one layer deep? Add some sort of visual indication like rene's script? Fix the fossilized username strings? Something?

Comment: They are good articles, but comments are absolutely not meant for discussions so they miss the mark a little. There is the other side of the coin however: features like this make it way too easy for people to start using comments like discussion tools. As such I say no threading should be involved; just one level of nesting. Comment - replies to comment.

Comment: Giving users a new ability to delete a certain class of comments of others (responses) is non-trivial.  Commenters then need to consider which reply they use.  Or the deletion functionality could be itself changed to blank the deleted comment (e.g. "[deleted]") while preserving the thread, but that would be an additional feature change.  At the very least, this should be considered as part of the request.

Comment: While I understand the sentiment here, I think that this is not *enough* of a problem to unleash the can of worms that would result.

Comment: If people are going to use comments like chat, why not just eliminate them? (The comments, not the people.) I mean, instead of "Let's continue this in chat" just start it out in chat.

Comment: I'd prefer a reply system like in chat, i.e. a 1-dimensional representation, but you can highlight the comment(s) replied to when hovering the comment.

Comment: Also a discussion is more like a [DAG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph) anyway, so a tree-like representation is not the best..

Comment: The irony of discussion in chat to not use chat as a discussion medium... I agree with the sentiment. I would like to see at least a slightly improved form of comments.

Comment: FWIW, [this idea has been discussed on MSE and its dupes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274383/comment-hierarchy-on-se) with controversial score.

Comment: I think it's a good design choice. Most websites I've been to comment sections in have comment secitons like the one proposed..

Comment: The irony is comments are being used for discussion here.

Comment: Also I have to completely disagree: Since comments are comments and not for discussion, indenting replies actually ENCOURAGES discussion.  Comments are better as they are.

Comment: I use the [Threaded comments](//stackapps.com/q/2050) script. It works, *up to a point*, and I often disable the threading on a specific post to ensure I get the right comment order. Note that many replies do *not* have a `@name` prefix (they are not available for the author when there is only one non-author commenter on a post, for example).

Comment: According to the [help], comments are for: "You should submit a comment if you want to: Request clarification from the author; Leave constructive criticism that guides the author in improving the post; Add relevant but minor or transient information to a post (e.g. a link to a related question, or an alert to the author that the question has been updated)." – So, in all examples of "good" comments, they are directed at the author. Okay, then, why even make them visible to everybody else? If comments are for communicating with and to the author, then nobody but the author needs to see them.

Comment: If, OTOH, comments are meant for the community at large, then it makes sense to organize them in some fashion. (Yes, I know, I am creating a false dichotomy here. Indulge me.)

Comment: @JörgWMittag Then a post author could be flooded by multiple comments saying the same thing, visitor will have to write a comment instead of voting for one already stating their remark. And no one can give feedback on this comment neither, that doesn't sound a good idea.

Answer (score 5):

Since becoming a moderator, I've focused on comment moderation, so I may be well situated to answer this question.

The ideal Q&A would be just that: a Q&A. A short meaningful question, followed by a multiple excellent answers, that provide correct information in various ways. Comments can be noise that gets in the way of the answers.

There are two kinds of quite appropriate comments - ones made on questions and ones made on answers.

Comments on questions should attempt to get the asker to provide whatever additional information is necessary to answer the question.

Comments on answers should ideally provide constructive criticism to the answer with the goal of improving them.

After the goals have been accomplished, the comments are obsolete and subject to deletion.

Ideally, comments should not be used to answer. Comments are subject to deletion, they cannot be downvoted, and answers go in the answers. If really good information is in a comment, ideally it would get edited into an answer, and then the comment is obsolesced and subject to deletion.

Ideally, comments should not be used for chat. Chat is available for chat, with a very small minimum reputation hurdle to get in.

Our system of comments is great.

Let's not change it.

What should we change? If you think comments are getting too chatty, rude, or just quite too long with back-and-forth conversation with multiple threads, please flag them for the reason that best applies to document the reason they should be deleted.

A commenter says:

> You sure are using "ideally" a lot in that answer of yours... Reality does not necessary reflect how it should ideally work.

Ideals are important because they shape how we interact with the real world that we live in. When our reality does not match our ideals, we attempt to change the reality to better do so.

If we're smart, we then take a step back and look at those results and then question if our ideals should still be our ideals. However, when I do this, I come back to the same conclusion: This is a Q&A site, not a Q&A&Comment site.

> I might need a little more practice or training on how make comments obsolete through editing.

It's actually quite simple - fix the problem addressed by the comment, or explain why the comment is wrong, then flag the comment as obsolete. If your answer doesn't benefit from such a change, you can just respond to such a comment with your own comment - then flag the comment for chattiness.

If your flag is declined, you can always give a custom flag explaining to moderators why the comment has been made unnecessary.

Comment: You sure are using "ideally" a lot in that answer of yours... Reality does not necessary reflect how it should ideally work.

Comment: "When our reality does not match our ideals, we attempt to change the reality to better do so." I agree. The problem though is that you're suggesting we _not_  make any changes: "Comments are great as they are. Let's not change them." IMO comments are _not_ great as they are, and the fact that reality is so wildly different from the ideals you outline here is proof of that.

Comment: @AaronHall I don't think that merely telling people "remember to flag comments" is going to change anything. The problems that exist with comments today are due to flaws inherent in the system, some of which would be addressed by a comment threading system. That's my take on it anyway.

Comment: @Ajedi32 Partly flaws with the system, partly flaws with the human race. This system would work significantly better if you were all robots.

Comment: I like this answer. It makes me think, though, that I might need a little more practice or training on how make comments obsolete through editing. I may add a new meta post about it after I have had more time to consider the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, replies are fine for me. Coming from a gaming chat background, separating lists of conversations is second nature to me. What I don't like is how the `show X more comments` feature hides comments in the middle of the chain. I'd much rather have it cut off the comments section than do whatever it does now. The way it is now, you have to scroll down to the bottom and click the link on every comment chain to avoid out-of-context comments.

Comment: "Whatever it does now" is hide low-score comments in favor of high-score comments. I quite like this behavior, as the vast majority of time the only comments in a long conversation that are really useful to me are the ones that have the most upvotes.

Comment: Like @Nathan, I too am in favor of hiding the low score comments. Too many comments are distracting and make it take longer to scroll down to the next answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have no objection to the way comments work now on StackOverflow save one: I don't have the ability to flag a comment directly as "this is an answer, not a comment."  I see many questions that go "unanswered" because the answer was given in a comment.  The questioner took the answer and left, there being no "official" answer to accept.

Comment: In this case you can add an answer yourself and then mark the comment as obsolete, especially if it is an old comment. Sometimes I answer in a comment because I don't have the time to write what I consider would be a decent answer.

Answer (score -1):

My preferred solution to this would be to have @replies be dynamic links.

Whenever someone changes their username, all @replies to them would be automatically updated.

Clicking (or even hovering) on an @reply could highlight all comments on that post by that user.

---

This is more a small step in the right direction as opposed to a significant UI redesign, as you suggested. It would hopefully require significantly less development work and can be done without having to start from scratch in determining which comments to show or whether too much or too little is shown (as it will stay the same in this regard).

I feel like the comment system is pretty decent as is, the main problems being that it's sometimes irritating to not know what comment a comment was replying to and/or having to search for it (especially in cases where that involves expanding the comments first, having the reply end up about 2 pages down, and then you first have to search for *that* again, before you even start searching for the thing you're looking for).

Comment: You're solving a problem that only exists when comments get too chatty. That's a flag reason that will lead to the deletion of those comments.

Comment: @AaronHall It has the same motivation as the question. In my (flagging) experience, mods are fairly hesitant to delete comments that might possibly, maybe have a chance to be useful at some point. And many popular answers have dozens of comments per answer that are seemingly useful. Sure, they should probably be edited into the answer, but the point is that no-one is doing that. There's also a grey area (IMO, at least) where something gets clarified that doesn't appear to be useful enough to be put in an answer, but is useful enough to not get deleted.

Comment: @Dukeling, replying to your comment, yes, this expresses well the problem I have had with cleaning up long comment lists below popular questions/answers.

Comment: @Dukeling, replying to your answer, I would also be quite satisfied with your preferred solution. I made my feature request because those things weren't being implemented.

Answer (score -3):

Yes, comment threading (at least one level deep) would be an extremely helpful feature on Stack Overflow; particularly due to the nature of how comments here are supposed to work. Allow me to explain.

Regarding the purpose of comments on Stack Overflow, the help center [states](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment):

> **When should I comment?**
>
> You should submit a comment if you want to:
>
> - Request **clarification** from the author;
> - Leave **constructive criticism** that guides the author in improving the post;
> - Add relevant but **minor or transient information** to a post (e.g. a link to a related question, or an alert to the author that the question has been updated).

Notice that all of the listed reasons for commenting are designed to allow users to point out an issue of some sort with the post the comment is being left on. They indicate either missing information, or some other problem with a post that its author may wish to fix.

The problem however is that none of those reasons for submitting a comment even allows for the possibility of commenting in reply to another comment on the post. In reality such comments are extremely common, and often helpful and necessary.

For example, if the original comment was requesting clarification from the author, replies to that comment often include interpretations from other users about what the author meant, or further questions from the author themselves about exactly where the commenter's confusion lies. Or if the original comment was constructive criticism, replies to that comment tend to be suggestions about the best way to address that criticism, or counter-arguments as to why the criticism is unwarranted.

In such cases it's easy for these replies to top-level comments to grow into a full-blown discussion. When that happens, users are *supposed* to move said discussion to chat, but in reality that rarely ever happens (for a lot of reasons I'm not going to get into here, but which *could* be fixed through better UX IMO). If multiple top-level comments exist, things can get even more cluttered as discussions and replies to top-level comments become intermixed with each other.

So how could threading help with this?

Well, let's imagine for a minute that Stack Overflow introduced just one extra level of comment threading. This would provide the following benefits:

1. Top-level comments would (at least ideally) *always* reflect some sort of issue with the main post. Replies and discussion surrounding the points made in those comments would be confined to their own little sub-threads, preventing them from interfering with other top-level comments which more directly relate to the main post.
2. If the post gets edited and a top-level comment becomes obsolete as a result (i.e. the issue in the main post it addresses is fixed), the entire thread could be collapsed or deleted without leaving any orphaned comments replying to it. This would further reduce noise in comments without creating an additional burden on moderators (who would otherwise have to sort through the conversation to determine what's obsolete and what isn't, assuming anyone even bothers flagging the conversation at all).
3. Since replies would no longer be top-level comments; top-level comments could be given a different name which encourages users to use them for their intended purpose. Maybe "issue" or "improvement request"? (Right now that name wouldn't make sense because replies are obviously not improvement requests, but with this proposal replies would no longer be top-level comments.)
4. Moderators would gain the ability to easily collapse, delete, or migrate a single thread to chat without affecting other top-level comments or replies to them.
5. The "move discussion to chat" link that appears during long conversations in comments could be triggered by thread length rather than relying on a long back-and-forth conversation between exactly two people.

All in all, it seems like a great idea to me.

---

Below are some possible arguments against this proposal I've seen, and my responses:

> Q: But won't adding threaded comments encourage people to (incorrectly) use comments for discussion by making discussion easier?
>
> A: People *already* use comments for discussion. This proposal would help limit the amount of noise those discussions generated by making things better-organized and making it easier for moderators and regular users to clean things up after the fact. Also, no I don't believe this would substantially increase the number of people using comments for discussion so long as the rules regarding what comments are intended to be used for remain the same.

-

> Q: But Jeff Atwood said flat discussions are better? ([Source 1](https://blog.codinghorror.com/discussions-flat-or-threaded/), [Source 2](https://blog.codinghorror.com/web-discussions-flat-by-design/))
>
> A: I personally disagree with Jeff's opinion here, but didn't we agree that comments are *not* supposed to be for discussion in the first place? Additionally, I'm only advocating for a single level of nesting here, which is a format that most of Jeff's arguments in those articles do not apply to.

-

> Q: But doesn't this make it possible for helpful comments to be lost when the parent commenter deletes their comment?
>
> A: That's actually a fair criticism of this system. (Or at least the version of it I'm envisioning here; there's nothing about threaded comments that inherently requires child comments to be deleted when the parent comment is removed.) The way I'm envisioning it, top-level comments would behave a bit like GitHub issues. The parent commenter has the ability to arbitrarily close/collapse their own issue, but if you feel there's still a problem with the original post that hasn't been addressed you can always create a new issue/top-level comment.

-

> Q: Wouldn't it be a lot of work to develop a system like this?
>
> A: Yes. I believe the benefits are significant enough to make it worth it, but as with any new feature it's up to the Stack Overflow staff to prioritize which features they believe would provide the greatest value to the community and implement those first.

Comment: So, judging by the votes on this I guess the community seems to generally disagree with this proposal? (Which seems odd to me given the number of upvotes on the feature-request/question itself.) Does anyone have any specific reasoning as to why they think would be a bad idea? Because it I honestly can't think of any reason _not_ to do something like this other than a general aversion to change.

Comment: Not a downvoter, but this answer highlights a few problems with the proposal for me - (1) replies are sometimes more useful than the original comment, the current system shows the "most useful" comments, the new system would either mostly always show the same comments or be really complicated, confusing and show too much, (2) having a single comment deleted should not automatically delete a whole bunch of other comments, sometimes the other comments are still useful, sometimes people delete comments for reasons other than it being obsolete, if they were left around, the question is how.

Comment: This also proposes to do a lot more development work on the comment system (than the original proposal), which I'm not sure I'm a fan of, as I'd rather have them work on "more important" features. I feel like the original proposal already probably required too much work.

Comment: @Dukeling Fair points. Though it's pretty much trivial to delete a parent comment without deleting its children. That's standard behavior on every threaded commenting system I've ever used (Reddit, Hacker News, Disqus, etc). Though if we're thinking of comments as "improvement requests" I'm not sure why you'd want replies to stick around after the parent comment is no longer relevant (whether because it's obsolete, or because the author deleted it). Presumably if the comment was directly relevant to the original post you'd post it as a separate improvement request, right?

Comment: I think you might be overestimating people's ability to strictly follow the rules and unambiguously communicate information, because once there starts being multiple issues raised per comment, or someone raises an additional issue in a reply, or there needs to be a bit of a back and forth to figure out what the user is requesting, it all kind of starts falling apart in my mind.

Comment: @Dukeling Yeah, that's a problem anytime you try to impose any kind of structure on human communication. (Hence all the people on SO posting comments in answers, answers in comments, questions in answers, etc.) In this case I believe some structure is better than none at all; especially if the goal is to try to keep comments focused on suggesting improvements to the post they're on. I could be wrong though.

Comment: Basically replace the comment system with the improvement request system of Docs.SO. I like this idea because it would foster an instinct to want to satisfy the improvement requests so they can be cleared and deleted.

Comment: @TinyGiant its an interesting train of thought; rather than organising the comments, to replace it with something more organised. Improvement requests sound like a really good idea to me.